# Set Intellij Idea Compiler Language Level to 1.3

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sdk

I'm using Intellij Idea 15.0.1 and have a Java project, it imports class of default package from the class of a named package.

Since it is allowed only in Java 1.3, I've set JDK 1.3 everywhere:
- Project Settings
- IDE Settings - Java Compiler
- Edit Configurations (Application)

But still when I make project it stops with "Cannot resolve symbol" error. Also making starts with the message:

`Information:Using javac 1.8.0_51 to compile java sources`

Why Idea still uses javac 1.8 and how to set java 1.3 for the whole project, including syntax highlight?

Comment: Which systems still require Java 1.3? Java 1.3 is so old it pre-dates EOL dates.

Comment: It is used in retail - as Point of Sale application

Comment: You have my sympathies.

Comment: Appreciate that. Project still can be successfully built, because it uses an ant script and javac.exe 1.3, but to debug it I have to comment some piece of code. That's kinda uncomfortablе.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install JDK 1.3, configure it in Project Structure | SDKs and select it as the project SDK in Project Structure | Project.

Comment: I've done everything you described (except of installing jdk 1.3 - just copied it to Java folder) - still no effect.

Comment: Please check the settings of your module (the Dependencies tab) and ensure that it has the correct "Module SDK" selected.

Comment: Checked - everywhere 1.3. Tried setting both Project SDK 1.3 and 1.3 itself. Just in case performed Invalidate cache/Restart. Same error(

Comment: yole, as member of of JetBrains, could you please specify which javac does Idea use for syntax check at design time? I guess it is some inner Idea java, because it's version does not match any of Java installed on my  computer

Comment: IntelliJ does not use any version of javac for syntax check at design time. It uses its own implementation of Java parsing and analysis. You can define the syntax version it uses for analysis in Project Structure | Project | Project language level.

Comment: Have you got 1.3 set in your Environment Variables?